# What is the difference between a tech tree and crafting?

Tags: game-mechanics

Are tech trees and crafting the same thing, except the mechanism to attain them?  What the real difference between the two?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a game-development question; what exactly are you trying to achieve? Are you implementing tech trees or crafting? What kind of game are you making?

Comment: @Johnny. An indirect way to get the answer you are looking for could to be to ask two questions (one per term) asking for the definitions of the two terms and how to implement them.

Comment: This question is ambiguous mainly because a "tech tree" is a fairly defined concept that adheres to commonalities across different games and even genres.  "Crafting" is incredibly varied and has no commonly accepted form or definition.  It ranges from simply clicking a single button to combine objects to complete mini-games with their own game-loops, rewards, challenges, etc.

Answer (score 1):

They do have similarities.

A tech tree is something you advance through in order to gain a skill or ability.  Crafting you also advance through, but you gain the ability to create something.

Potentially, you could share the same base data structures between them.